# SQLException on Android

Tags: android, sqlite, exception

ALL,

I'm trying to create following table in Android application:

```
CREATE TABLE order(product_id integer);
```

but it gives me an exception that says:

```
near order: syntax error: CREATE TABLE order(product_id integer);
```

Is order or product_id reserved word in SQLite?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes `order` is a keyword in SQLite (and all other databases I think).

Did You even try to google it? I can't belive that asking a question here is faster than finding [list of keyword in SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) considering You had a clue what may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot name your table as order because it a reserved word in any database. Try changing it.